# Is the WalletConnect supporting the "Binance Smart Chain (BEP20)" wallets?

Tags: android, binance, metamask, binance-smart-chain, wallet-connect

I was checking **Kotlin WalletConnect App** and it is working fine for the *Etherium ERC20*.

**But I need to know is this possible to use this App for the Binance Smart Chain (BEP20) transactions?**

**If Yes, can you please share the methods?**

I checked the code and it shows the methods of eth_SendTransaction & eth_sign methods. *But could not find anything related to Binance Smart Chain (BEP20).*

**Trust Wallet:**
When I tried to use the WalletConnect Kotlin Sample App with Trust Wallet, it give me the "Wallet not supported" message.

**MetaMask:**
When I tried to use the WalletConnect Kotlin Sample App with MetaMask, it gives me no response. MetaMask opens but nothing happens over there.
In the case of Etherium, when I press the "Connect" button, it opens the MetaMask app and gives the prompt to connect the MetaMask Wallet to WalletConnect App, it works successfully and I get the "Connected" status on my WalletConnect App upon tapping the connect in MetaMask. Now when I tap over the "Send Sample Transaction" on the WalletConnect App, a new prompt appears in the MetaMask App with the requesting Transaction App to authorize. It works fine in the case of ETH, but not in the case of BEP20.

Comment: For transactions, methods are same (eth_SendTransaction ...) for BSC.